# Java Kerberos SSO and Windows NT-ENTERPRISE name type

Tags: java, kerberos

There are issues with users authenticating against a Java Kerberos enabled SSO app. It seems that login fails when Windows sends a name type of NT-ENTERPRISE instead of NT-PRINCIPAL.

I looked at javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal, and the NT-ENTERPRISE type seems to be unsupported. What can we do? Is there a way to prevent Windows from using that type?

We only have one realm, so I don't know why this type is even used. Also, this problem affects only some clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not support the enterprise principal format. This does not matter actually. When the client presents a service ticket, the KDC always translates the eUPN to a iUPN, so Kerberos always uses the implicit UPN.

Note: Windows does that by default. MIT Kerberos requires `canonicalize` to be `true`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that the KDC maps the user, but isn't the eUPN presented to the Kerberos enabled app? I'm still not getting why this is transparent to the JVM.

Comment: No, the eUPN is presented to the KDC only. You can download MS' resource kit. There is a `klist` implementation. Log on to your computer with your enterprise principal and check the credential cache. You'll see the iUPN only. The a client sends a `TGS-REQ` it does that with its iUPN. The issued service ticket by the KDC contains your **iUPN** and the target SPN. Your Java app will see that iUPN in the service ticket only.

Comment: Thnaks, seems thats actually the case. Marked answer as correct.